# Android Eclipse - error trying to open or edit /res/values/strings.xml - NullPointerException

Tags: android, eclipse, string, nullpointerexception, edit

getting error:

An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
java.lang.NullPointerException

when I attempt to edit this file in my eclipse Android sdk project.

Not seeing anything in LogCat or the Console.

I need to update this file to rename the Project.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [this question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444040/naming-my-application-in-android)  According to it, the application's name is set to be the name of any activity that declares

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

The app_name, in this case, may not be of any significance, because the name of the application is being set by the component activities of the application, rather than by the application itself.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the XML/XML Files/Editor preference page and turn off the "Use inferred grammar..." setting.

Source: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/5ea69f7367b725a5/3ff91fea09a34b4a