# Android Application Name Appears as Activity Name

Tags: android

I have reviewed the manifest for application, and under apps launcher it displays as Activity Name rather than its app name?  Why is this. I have another application where when I install it, there are 5 entries one for each activity in the application when there should be just one name, that of the app? So when I go to launch it has 5 identically named apps in the launch list. These are named after the app but there is one for each activity.   What could be the reason for this?

Comment: This seems strange.  I mean why should android even allow multiple apps with the same name to appear in the app launch list?

Comment: Please paste your manifest contents.

Comment: One of the issues is that for the multiple apps with same name is too many laucher category activities.

Comment: <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

Comment: I think this explains what I am seeing for second application.

Comment: but why is the activity name used as the app name?  What is the reason for this?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.mycompany.test"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:name="TestApp"  android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:debuggable="true" android:label="@string/app_name">

Comment: and I have checked that string.xml does have an app_name which is correct.

Comment: Problem solved and detailed here -> [Naming my application in android](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23155350/3420447)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For the first issue, you should be aware that in absence of a label on the launching `Activity` the name comes from the default label set in the `android:label` attribute on the application tag:

```
<application android:name="ApiDemosApplication"
   android:label="@string/activity_sample_code"
   android:icon="@drawable/app_sample_code">
```

If the `Activity` has a label, that label will be used instead.

For the second issue, in the manifest, it is likely that all your activities specify an intent filter with an action of android.intent.category.LAUNCHER. For example:

```
<activity android:name="ApiDemos">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

If you have such intent-filter tags on all activities, you should take out the intent filter tags on all but the `Activity` that you want to launch at startup. If this `Activity` has a label, it is the label that will be shown along with the launcher icon.

As of 2019/01/03 on API 27+, it appears that the first activity with the `LAUNCHER` category will be launched and its label will be associated with the app icon, so it may not be strictly necessary to remove all the redundant intent filters, but I'd do it anyway because it can lead to confusion.

Comment: Ok.  So the without the label it will pick the name for an main activity.

Comment: Still seems like launchers entries should be for the app and not based on activities at all, but this was the problem

Comment: actual I do have an android label in the manifest I posted above??

Comment: android:label="@string/app_name"

Comment: I see the problem I referenced string.xml when I was looking for strings.xml with s.  So misspelled could not find it.

Comment: The LAUNCHER category is setting up the Activity that launches when you touch the icon in the Launcher. If there are multiple Activities that respond to the Intent (because of the category tags), the framework can't figure out what to launch and asks the user.

Comment: I had the same problem but fixed it by changing android:name in the <Activity /> that has <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> and <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

Answer (score 46):

The above accepted answer is wrong. It says,

> the name comes from the android:label attribute on the application tag

That's not true. Take the following code for example.

```
<activity android:name="ApiDemos" android:label="@string/app_name">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

In this code, the app name that shows in the launcher is set by the `android:label` attribute in the `activity` tag not the `application` tag as the above accepted answer says.

To correct the above accepted response, the name shown under the icon in the launcher comes from the `android:label` attribute in the entry point activity's `activity` tag (the activity tag that contains the `DEFAULT` and `LAUNCHER` categories) unless you don't specify it there in which case it comes from the `android:label` attribute on the `application` tag.

Your first issue can be solved by changing the `android:label` attribute in your entry point activity's tag.

Comment: What a strange behaviour. It would seem more logical to use the activity name for the activity, and the app name for the launcher. Do you see any sense in it working just how it does?

Comment: It's so app devs can have more than one launcher icon (and associated entry point activity) and are able to have separate names for each launcher icon. You can do this by including the following code in more than one activity tag in the manifest:
`<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>`
and adding `android:label="@string/app_name"` to each activity tag.

Comment: @Patrick so how can i put label for the entry activity seperated from application name? if i am willing to have only one main activity?

Answer (score 8):

One way to have a different application name (the name that appears under the app icon) and a different name for the activity that is being launched when you tap on the app icon is to explicitly set a different string in the activity's onCreate() method, like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  // Do your thing
  // ... bla bla bla

  getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.activity_title);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Use [`getSupportActionBar()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27712413/4084269) instead of `getActionBar()` if you are using the support library

Answer (score 2):

When you create an Activity via Eclipse, the property android:label inside your activity is automatically set to "@string/your_activity_name" in the AndroidManifest.xml. Adding the intent filter to provide a launcher for this activity, your launcher gets the same label as your Activities android:label.

If you want to label the launcher with your application name, you should change the Activities android:label to something like "@string/app_name".

Answer (score 1):

As if you want to place a image view in the place of toolbar title. You have to update the label of particular activity in the android manifest as `android:label="";` by doing this your activity name won't gets displayed in the toolbar after the image view and please use the following code for setting image view along with navigation icon and no toolbar title.

```
try {
    Toolbar  toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("");
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null)
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.header_image_wt);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Running Android version 4.1.2 the name of the application will be "static" with respect to the label defined in the activity set as main launcher and not overridden in any intent filters