# BluetoothChat example: NullPointerException

Tags: android, bluetooth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [getActionBar returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10031180/getactionbar-returns-null)

Complete Android noob. I am trying to run the BluetoothChat example from a Galaxy S3, and it appears to crash the moment the application is run.

Here is the LogCat output:

```
09-14 15:47:23.400: E/AndroidRuntime(6098): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-14 15:47:23.400: E/AndroidRuntime(6098): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-14 15:47:23.400: E/AndroidRuntime(6098):     at com.example.android.BluetoothChat.BluetoothChat.setStatus(BluetoothChat.java:235)
09-14 15:47:23.400: E/AndroidRuntime(6098):     at com.example.android.BluetoothChat.BluetoothChat.access$4(BluetoothChat.java:233)
09-14 15:47:23.400: E/AndroidRuntime(6098):     at com.example.android.BluetoothChat.BluetoothChat$2.handleMessage(BluetoothChat.java:260)
09-14 15:47:23.400: E/AndroidRuntime(6098):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-14 15:47:23.400: E/AndroidRuntime(6098):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-14 15:47:23.400: E/AndroidRuntime(6098):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
09-14 15:47:23.400: E/AndroidRuntime(6098):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-14 15:47:23.400: E/AndroidRuntime(6098):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-14 15:47:23.400: E/AndroidRuntime(6098):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
09-14 15:47:23.400: E/AndroidRuntime(6098):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
09-14 15:47:23.400: E/AndroidRuntime(6098):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Code is exactly per the example in the SDK:

```
private final void setStatus(int resId) {
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setSubtitle(resId);
}
```

It appears getActionBar returns null. What might I be doing incorrectly?

This is only the 2nd Android app I have run, so go easy on me :)

Cheers

Comment: post the code where ur getting these errors

Comment: you can check the line number 235 and 260. But to make it more clear post you code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solution found here: [getActionBar returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10031180/getactionbar-returns-null)

this needs to go to the `onCreate()` method in `bluetoothChat.java`

> getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);

Comment: Yes, it worked for me. You need to add it before "setContentView(R.layout.main);".