# Android Sample Bluetooth chat

Tags: android, bluetooth, forceclose

I have tried the sample code of Bluetooth chat from Android SDK. The code has no errors, Installed the APK on device, while opening the Bluetooth chat, Force close is thrown.

I used a real device to debug, i.e. Galaxy Nexus S.

Please help me . 
. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @lokesh and anoop Okay .. the code is in the documentation itself named Bluetooth chat . I observed that if I remove the following line mBluetoothAdapter =     BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(); , no exception is thrown . One more thing , i have android revision 15 and I am running it on jelly beans in galaxy nexus . Thanks for commenting guys . I am waiting for my answer .

Answer (score 5):

I managed to fix it by:

1. Changing the AndroidManifest.xml: Basically upgrading the versions where it works `<uses-sdk android:maxSdkVersion="17" android:targetSdkVersion="11" android:minSdkVersion="11"/>` the 11th version is Android 3.0 (Honeycomb).
2. Also deleted the line in the AndroidManifest.xml referring to the style `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog"`
3. The main activity is BluetoothChat, so looking in the logCat I could see what else is throwing exceptions, the method setStatus around 233 is throwing a NullPointerEception due that the onCreate method needs the following code just bellow the super.onCreate call. Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10031180/getactionbar-returns-null) post 
       `getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this still applies for you, but i encountered the same problem.

I downloaded the sample, loaded it on a Samsung S3(jellybean) and it kept crashing after the prompt for Bluetooth. There wasn't any error at first. So i tried using your method of removing 
`mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()`
in the code (on eclipse) and was prompted that it was read only and whether i want to make it writable. Upon doing that a few error came up and that was a prompt to say getDefaultAdapter is for API 5 and current minSdk is 1. Hence i looked up into the manifest file to see why it would be a problem since i put it as minSdkVersion=5.

Upon making the manifest file writable as previously mentioned for the java file, i realized the error was due to this line

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog"`

it requires an API of 11. Hence i changed to android:minSdkVersion="11" and now it works perfectly.