# NullPointerException on implementation of Tab Layout

Tags: java, android, layout, tabs, nullpointerexception

I've implemented Tab Layout and my app is not starting. I get NullPointerException on this line:

```
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

I think that everything is done properly. I can't find my mistake.

MainActivity:

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

import com.msh.numeral_system_converter_adapter.TabsPagerAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener {

private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;

// Tab titles
private String[] tabs = { "Converter", "Calculator"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Initilization
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    //actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }

    /**
     * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
     * */
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // on tab selected
    // show respected fragment view
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}
```

}

Log file:

```
04-11 17:44:02.553    1545-1545/com.msh.numeral_system_converter E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.msh.numeral_system_converter, PID: 1545
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.msh.numeral_system_converter/com.msh.numeral_system_converter.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.msh.numeral_system_converter.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
```

Comment: can you post your manifest ? more precisely the value of the `android:theme` attribute !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getActionBar()` can retrun `null` if your window don't have an `ActionBar`. Like if you chose the `Theme.NoTitleBar` style as an Activity/Application theme.

Use this code instead ([picked from there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10031180/getactionbar-returns-null)):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

// The Action Bar is a window feature. The feature must be requested
// before setting a content view. Normally this is set automatically
// by your Activity's theme in your manifest. The provided system
// theme Theme.WithActionBar enables this for you. Use it as you would
// use Theme.NoTitleBar. You can add an Action Bar to your own themes
// by adding the element <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
// to your style definition.
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

// experiment with the ActionBar 
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
}
```

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867076/getactionbar-returns-null) also may help.

Comment: Thank You. I enabled action bar and everything is ok. My fault :(

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
actionBar = getActionBar();
mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
//actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

You assign actionBar from the getActionBar() method, but you didn't provide that code.  My guess is that `getActionBar()` is returning null.   The NullPointerException is coming from trying to call `setNavigationMode` on a null object, probably not from referencing the field on `ActionBar`.

Answer (score 0):

Using above fix you may get another error :-

> requestFeature() must be called before adding content

to solve that problem use this fix :-

Don't call `setContentView()` before `requestFeature()`.

Answer (score 0):

This exception arises when you have selected a theme with no `ActionBar`.
Try using a theme like,

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```