# getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-actionbar

I am trying to demo a Navigation Drawer example, but I have some trouble, may anyone help me?
Here is my code:

```
package app.android.example.com.navigationdrawer;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mleftList, mrightList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private ArrayList arrLeft, arrRight;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initArrayForListViewDrawer();

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mleftList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        mrightList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.right_drawer);

        mleftList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ban da tab chon Setting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                Log.d("debug", "click left " + position);
                mleftList.setItemChecked(position, true);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mleftList);
            }
        });

        mrightList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.d("debug", "click right " + position);
                mrightList.setItemChecked(position, true);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mrightList);
            }
        });

        ItemAdapter adapterLeft = new ItemAdapter(this, arrLeft);
        mleftList.setAdapter(adapterLeft);

        ItemAdapter adapterRight = new ItemAdapter(this, arrRight);
        mrightList.setAdapter(adapterRight);

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.ic_action_favorite, GravityCompat.START);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer,
                R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
            public void OnDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle("Close DrawerLayout");
                Log.d("debug", "OnDrawerClose");
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle("Open DrawerLayout");
                Log.d("debug", "OnDrawerOpened");
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }

    private void initArrayForListViewDrawer() {
        arrLeft = new ArrayList();
        arrRight = new ArrayList();

        ItemNavigation ItemNavigation1 = new ItemNavigation(R.drawable.ic_action_settings, "Settings");
        arrLeft.add(ItemNavigation1);
        ItemNavigation ItemNavigation2 = new ItemNavigation(R.drawable.ic_action_new, "Add new");
        arrLeft.add(ItemNavigation2);
        ItemNavigation ItemNavigation3 = new ItemNavigation(R.drawable.ic_action_favorite, "Favorite");
        arrLeft.add(ItemNavigation3);
        ItemNavigation ItemNavigation4 = new ItemNavigation(R.drawable.ic_action_collection, "Foder");
        arrLeft.add(ItemNavigation4);
        ItemNavigation ItemNavigation5 = new ItemNavigation(R.drawable.ic_action_about, "About");
        arrLeft.add(ItemNavigation5);
        ItemNavigation ItemNavigation11 = new ItemNavigation(R.drawable.ic_action_settings, "Settings");
        arrRight.add(ItemNavigation11);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("debug", "onPostCreate");
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        Log.d("debug", "onConfigurationChanged");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        Log.d("debug", "onPrepareOptionsMenu");
        boolean drawerleftOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mleftList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(!drawerleftOpen);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_st).setVisible(!drawerleftOpen);
        boolean drawerrightOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mrightList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(!drawerrightOpen);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(!drawerrightOpen);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(!drawerrightOpen);

        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_bar, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                Log.d("debug", "click home");
                boolean drawerleftOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mleftList);
                if (!drawerleftOpen) {
                    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.START);
                } else {
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mleftList);
                }

                break;
            case R.id.action_st:
                Log.d("debug", "click setting");
                boolean drawerrightOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mrightList);
                if (!drawerrightOpen) {
                    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.END);
                } else {
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mrightList);
                }
                break;

            case R.id.action_search:
                Log.d("debug", "click Search");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Here is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/framelayout">
        </FrameLayout>

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="#111"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/white"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            ></ListView>

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:background="#111"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            ></ListView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the log show:

```
09-11 13:40:52.371  11674-11674/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: app.android.example.com.navigationdrawer, PID: 11674
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{app.android.example.com.navigationdrawer/app.android.example.com.navigationdrawer.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at app.android.example.com.navigationdrawer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I dont know what is wrong and dont know how to resolve this.

Comment: Use `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()`

Comment: `getActionBar()` is returning `null` in `onCreate`. Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10031180/getactionbar-returns-null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that your theme is not one with an actionbar. Also you should be using `getSupportActionBar()` instead. Wrap your actionbar code in a null check for best practice though. There are some situations where the actionbar might not have been created/set in the lifecycle.

Answer (score 2):

Why ActionBarActivity ? Have you tried with AppCompatActivity?

Moreover where did you specified your ActionBar in xml? Is it in toolbar.xml file?

```
  toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Make sure you have this in your DrawerLayout xml.