# Android Studio: Using ImageButton to start new activity crashes the app

Tags: java, android, xml, imagebutton

I am designing an app that has a home screen with 6 image buttons, that all start new activities.

Currently when I press the button, the app crashes. This is strange however as I have done this project with regular buttons and it works fine, and I have also made it so when the image button is pressed it just prints "Clicked!" on thee screen and this also works fine, so the problem is starting a new activity.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.darren1.homemanagementsystem;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    findAllViewsById();
}


private void findAllViewsById(){

    ImageButton lightButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.lightButton);
    lightButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick (View v){


            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LightingActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="#feae5e"
android:clickable="true">

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="#feae5e"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="137dp"
        android:layout_height="133dp"
        android:id="@+id/cameraButton"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:src="@drawable/rsz_cameraicon"
        android:background="#feae5e" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/alarmButton"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="13"
        android:src="@drawable/rsz_alarmicon"
        android:background="#feae5e" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fireButton"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:src="@drawable/rsz_fireicon"
        android:background="#feae5e"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lightButton"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="13"
        android:src="@drawable/rsz_lightbulbicon"
        android:background="#feae5e"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/thermoButton"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:src="@drawable/rsz_1thermometericon"
        android:background="#feae5e"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tvButton"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="13"
        android:src="@drawable/rsz_1tvicon"
        android:background="#feae5e"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp" />

</GridLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.darren1.homemanagementsystem" >
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LightingActivity"
        android:label="Light" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".TelevisionActivity"
        android:label="TV">
    </activity>
</application>
```

**activity_lighting.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"     android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.darren1.homemanagementsystem.LightingActivity"
android:background="#beddeb">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/lighting"
        android:id="@+id/lightingView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="32dp" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="66dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/kitchen"
        android:id="@+id/kitchenLight" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/sittingroom"
        android:id="@+id/sittingroomLight"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/bedroom"
        android:id="@+id/bedroomLight"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/outside"
        android:id="@+id/outsideLight"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3">

    <Switch
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/switch1" />

    <Switch
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/switch2"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    <Switch
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/switch3"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    <Switch
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/switch4"
        android:checked="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/backButton"
        android:id="@+id/backButton"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#010101"
        android:textColor="#fefdfd"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**LightingActivity.java**
    package com.example.darren1.homemanagementsystem;

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class LightingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getActionBar().setTitle("Light");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lighting);


    onClickListenerButton();
}


public void onClickListenerButton(){


    Intent i = getIntent();




}
```

}

Comment: If the problem starts when going to your `LightningActivity` than please post your `LightningActivity` code and layout

Comment: Post your Logcat too

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10031180/getactionbar-returns-null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem I guess comes with this two lines :

```
 getActionBar().setTitle("Light");
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_lighting);
```

You should put frist the `setContentView()` and then the `Title` of your `ActionBar`

`If I were you I'd start using [`Toolbar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html)
Do the`setTitle()` as follows :

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setTitle("Light");
```

See this [answer for more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23731325/4385913)

Comment: ActionBar is not deprecated, it's navigation modes and tabs are.

Answer (score 0):

Not correct:
`setContentView(R.layout.activity_light);` -> activity_lighting.xml
Different name.

But you have another different name:
`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` -> activity_mainn.xml
(Maybe typing error)

Comment: Sorry, I posted the activity_light class from  a different project by mistake, it has been corrected now to the activity_lighting.java class