# Need to make Bluetooth chat sample application work on my Galaxy S3 or HTC EVO 4G

Tags: android, bluetooth, chat, sample

When I create a new BlueToothChat project on Eclipse, it compiles perfectly fine and I can then download it into my Galaxy S3 (running Android 4.1.1). If the BT is disabled, it asks for it to be enabled. When I do, the app goes in and then collapses with:

```
02-06 13:40:52.959: E/AndroidRuntime(25405): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-06 13:40:52.959: E/AndroidRuntime(25405): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.example.android.BluetoothChat.BluetoothChat.getActionBar
02-06 13:40:52.959: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at com.example.android.BluetoothChat.BluetoothChat.setStatus(BluetoothChat.java:234)
02-06 13:40:52.959: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at com.example.android.BluetoothChat.BluetoothChat.access$4(BluetoothChat.java:233)
02-06 13:40:52.959: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at com.example.android.BluetoothChat.BluetoothChat$2.handleMessage(BluetoothChat.java:260)
02-06 13:40:52.959: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-06 13:40:52.959: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
02-06 13:40:52.959: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4263)
02-06 13:40:52.959: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-06 13:40:52.959: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-06 13:40:52.959: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-06 13:40:52.959: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-06 13:40:52.959: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I then repeated the exact same test with an HTC EVO 4G running Android 2.3.5. Exact same problem!

I already found this question but the answer is no good. The explanation is that apparently the getActionBar() call generates a NULL. I tried both suggested solutions, but none of them solve the problem. Kind of annoying that a sample application, which is supposed to be flawless, doesn't work!

Any other suggestion on how to make the BlueTooth Chat Application work? I need to send serial data to an application and found a nice tutorial pretty much using this application, but kind of useless if the app collapses on different platforms. Thanks for any input you may be able to provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two ways to make the sample work on your devices. First just comment these lines of code so they won't compile. And the second way is just add `ActionBarSherlock` as library to your project and instead of `getActionBar()` use `getSupportActionBar()`.

Comment: Thanks! I went with the line commenting technique. They are not that necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily ingonre all the code associated with the action bar, or you can trace the source of the problem in this link [getActionBar return null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867076/getactionbar-returns-null)

According to android documentations, **Activity will return null if there is no action bar**

See this link : [Android getActionBar() Doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getActionBar%28%29)

Comment: Thanks! Commenting the lines worked out perfectly fine, so I am up and running. Trying to get the devices to connect now...