# NullPointerException in ActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled

Tags: java, android

Good evening.
I have `android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16"`

And I have a NullPointerException in onCreate method:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tain);

    mCollectionPagerAdapter = new CollectionPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());

    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

    //Here is the error
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);

    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mCollectionPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(
            new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                }
            });

        for (int i = 0; i < mCollectionPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                    .setText(mCollectionPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }

}
```

I have a simillar code in other project and it works right. The versions of the libraries in both projects are simillar too. What may caused this exception and what can I change?

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of Android are you using?

Comment: Which theme is your activity using? Does it have an ActionBar in it?

Comment: Yeah, that's a mistake. I  have   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"

Answer (score 17):

In your manifest make sure your activity has (of similar):

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
```

Answer (score 4):

your error is getting caused by the `getActionBar()` method.

Check this link:

[getActionBar() returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867076/getactionbar-returns-null)

Answer (score 2):

Remove android:theme="@style/AppTheme" in your manifest file

Answer (score 0):

Made following changes in AndroidManifest file works for me

```
 @android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar
```