# App has stopped (Jelly Bean 4.1.2)

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I'm using "searchable dictionary" sample code. Every application that I'm developing on Eclipse doesn't work in android 4.1.2 (it's always stopping the application), but in older versions works perfectly.

What's happening? Here is my code:

My logcat

```
12-02 11:45:40.012: W/ActivityThread(24344): Application com.pesquisa.dicionario.searchabledict can be debugged on port 8100...
12-02 11:45:40.102: I/ActivityThread(24344): Pub com.pesquisa.dicionario.searchabledict.DictionaryProvider: com.pesquisa.dicionario.searchabledict.DictionaryProvider
12-02 11:45:40.212: D/dalvikvm(24344): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 85K, 9% free 9453K/10307K, paused 32ms, total 32ms
12-02 11:45:40.232: I/dalvikvm-heap(24344): Grow heap (frag case) to 15.354MB for 5738164-byte allocation
12-02 11:45:40.282: D/dalvikvm(24344): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 6% free 15056K/15943K, paused 29ms+4ms, total 55ms
12-02 11:45:40.503: D/AbsListView(24344): Get MotionRecognitionManager
12-02 11:45:40.573: D/libEGL(24344): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_vc4.so
 12-02 11:45:40.573: D/(24344): SpyHook inactive - could not find libspyhook.so [Symbol not found: ] or not enabled (debug.egl.hw.spy = 0)
12-02 11:45:40.593: W/khrn_client(24344): init_window num_buffers 3 min undequeued buffers 1 type 1
12-02 11:45:40.593: W/khrn_client(24344): init_window window 0x40f296d0, 480x800 hintTransform 0x0
12-02 11:45:40.623: D/OpenGLRenderer(24344): Enabling debug mode 0
12-02 11:45:44.356: D/AbsListView(24344): Get MotionRecognitionManager
12-02 11:45:44.436: W/khrn_client(24344): init_window num_buffers 3 min undequeued buffers 1 type 1
12-02 11:45:44.436: W/khrn_client(24344): init_window window 0x4d5da008, 399x84 hintTransform 0x0
12-02 11:45:45.377: W/InputEventReceiver(24344): Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
 12-02 11:45:46.639: W/khrn_client(24344): init_window num_buffers 3 min undequeued buffers 1 type 1
12-02 11:45:46.639: W/khrn_client(24344): init_window window 0x4d5da008, 399x84 hintTransform 0x0
12-02 11:45:47.329: D/GestureDetector(24344): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 4 mFalseSizeCnt:0
12-02 11:45:47.449: E/SensorManager(24344): thread start
12-02 11:45:47.459: D/SensorManager(24344): registerListener :: handle = 4  name= MPL accel delay= 200000  
 12-02 11:45:47.559: W/khrn_client(24344): init_window num_buffers 3 min undequeued buffers 1 type 1
 12-02 11:45:47.559: W/khrn_client(24344): init_window window 0x4d5da008, 480x762 hintTransform 0x0
   12-02 11:45:47.840: E/SpannableStringBuilder(24344): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
  12-02 11:45:47.840: E/SpannableStringBuilder(24344): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
  12-02 11:45:48.490: W/khrn_client(24344): init_window num_buffers 3 min undequeued buffers 1 type 1
  12-02 11:45:48.490: W/khrn_client(24344): init_window window 0x4d5da008, 480x368 hintTransform 0x0
  12-02 11:45:50.102: D/AbsListView(24344): Get MotionRecognitionManager
  12-02 11:45:50.172: W/khrn_client(24344): init_window num_buffers 3 min undequeued buffers 1 type 1
   12-02 11:45:50.172: W/khrn_client(24344): init_window window 0x4db44430, 461x304 hintTransform 0x0
  12-02 11:45:51.353: D/GestureDetector(24344): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 3 mFalseSizeCnt:0
  12-02 11:45:51.543: D/SensorManager(24344): unregisterListener::  
   12-02 11:45:51.543: D/Sensors(24344): Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms
  12-02 11:45:51.543: I/Sensors(24344): sendDelay --- 200000000
  12-02 11:45:51.543: D/SensorManager(24344): JNI - sendDelay
  12-02 11:45:51.543: I/SensorManager(24344): Set normal delay = true
  12-02 11:45:51.593: D/AbsListView(24344): Get MotionRecognitionManager
  12-02 11:45:51.633: W/khrn_client(24344): init_window num_buffers 3 min undequeued buffers 1 type 1
   12-02 11:45:51.633: W/khrn_client(24344): init_window window 0x4d619928, 480x800 hintTransform 0x0
   12-02 11:45:51.643: D/AndroidRuntime(24344): Shutting down VM
  12-02 11:45:51.643: W/dalvikvm(24344): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x410f12a0)
   12-02 11:45:51.664: E/AndroidRuntime(24344): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  12-02 11:45:51.664: E/AndroidRuntime(24344): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pesquisa.dicionario.searchabledict/com.pesquisa.dicionario.searchabledict.WordActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
   12-02 11:45:51.664: E/AndroidRuntime(24344):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
  12-02 11:45:51.664: E/AndroidRuntime(24344):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
  12-02 11:45:51.664: E/AndroidRuntime(24344):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
  12-02 11:45:51.664: E/AndroidRuntime(24344):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
  12-02 11:45:51.664: E/AndroidRuntime(24344):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  12-02 11:45:51.664: E/AndroidRuntime(24344):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  12-02 11:45:51.664: E/AndroidRuntime(24344):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4935)
  12-02 11:45:51.664: E/AndroidRuntime(24344):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   12-02 11:45:51.664: E/AndroidRuntime(24344):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  12-02 11:45:51.664: E/AndroidRuntime(24344):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
  12-02 11:45:51.664: E/AndroidRuntime(24344):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
   12-02 11:45:51.664: E/AndroidRuntime(24344):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  12-02 11:45:51.664: E/AndroidRuntime(24344): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
   12-02 11:45:51.664: E/AndroidRuntime(24344):     at com.pesquisa.dicionario.searchabledict.WordActivity.onCreate(WordActivity.java:30)
  12-02 11:45:51.664: E/AndroidRuntime(24344):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
  12-02 11:45:51.664: E/AndroidRuntime(24344):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
  12-02 11:45:51.664: E/AndroidRuntime(24344):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
  12-02 11:45:51.664: E/AndroidRuntime(24344):  ... 11 more
```

DictionaryDatabase.java

```
package com.pesquisa.dicionario.searchabledict;

import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;
 import android.text.TextUtils;
 import android.util.Log;

 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStream;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.util.HashMap;

 import com.pesquisa.dicionario.searchabledict.R;


public class DictionaryDatabase {
private static final String TAG = "DictionaryDatabase";

public static final String KEY_WORD = SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1;
public static final String KEY_DEFINITION = SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_2;

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dictionary";
private static final String FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE = "FTSdictionary";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

private final DictionaryOpenHelper mDatabaseOpenHelper;
private static final HashMap<String,String> mColumnMap = buildColumnMap();

public DictionaryDatabase(Context context) {
    mDatabaseOpenHelper = new DictionaryOpenHelper(context);
}

private static HashMap<String,String> buildColumnMap() {
    HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    map.put(KEY_WORD, KEY_WORD);
    map.put(KEY_DEFINITION, KEY_DEFINITION);
    map.put(BaseColumns._ID, "rowid AS " +
            BaseColumns._ID);
    map.put(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID, "rowid AS " +
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID);
    map.put(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID, "rowid AS " +
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID);
    return map;
}

public Cursor getWord(String rowId, String[] columns) {
    String selection = "rowid = ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {rowId};

    return query(selection, selectionArgs, columns);

}

public Cursor getWordMatches(String query, String[] columns) {
    String selection = KEY_WORD + " MATCH ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {query+"*"};

    return query(selection, selectionArgs, columns);

}

private Cursor query(String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String[] columns) {

    SQLiteQueryBuilder builder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    builder.setTables(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE);
    builder.setProjectionMap(mColumnMap);

    Cursor cursor = builder.query(mDatabaseOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(),
            columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);

    if (cursor == null) {
        return null;
    } else if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        cursor.close();
        return null;
    }
    return cursor;
}

private static class DictionaryOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private final Context mHelperContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

    private static final String FTS_TABLE_CREATE =
                "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE +
                " USING fts3 (" +
                KEY_WORD + ", " +
                KEY_DEFINITION + ");";

    DictionaryOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        mHelperContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        mDatabase = db;
        mDatabase.execSQL(FTS_TABLE_CREATE);
        loadDictionary();
    }

    private void loadDictionary() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    loadWords();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private void loadWords() throws IOException {
        Log.d(TAG, "Loading words...");
        final Resources resources = mHelperContext.getResources();
        InputStream inputStream = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.definitions);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        try {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] strings = TextUtils.split(line, "//");
                if (strings.length < 2) continue;
                long id = addWord(strings[0].trim(), strings[1].trim());
                if (id < 0) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "unable to add word: " + strings[0].trim());
                }
            }
        } finally {
            reader.close();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "DONE loading words.");
    }


    public long addWord(String word, String definition) {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_WORD, word);
        initialValues.put(KEY_DEFINITION, definition);

        return mDatabase.insert(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

}
```

DictionaryProvider.java

```
package com.pesquisa.dicionario.searchabledict;


import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.UriMatcher;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;

public class DictionaryProvider extends ContentProvider {
String TAG = "DictionaryProvider";

public static String AUTHORITY = "com.pesquisa.dicionario.searchabledict.DictionaryProvider";
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/dictionary");

public static final String WORDS_MIME_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_DIR_BASE_TYPE +
                                              "/vnd.pesquisa.dicionario.searchabledict";
public static final String DEFINITION_MIME_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_ITEM_BASE_TYPE +
                                                   "/vnd.pesquisa.dicionario.searchabledict";

private DictionaryDatabase mDictionary;

private static final int SEARCH_WORDS = 0;
private static final int GET_WORD = 1;
private static final int SEARCH_SUGGEST = 2;
private static final int REFRESH_SHORTCUT = 3;
private static final UriMatcher sURIMatcher = buildUriMatcher();

private static UriMatcher buildUriMatcher() {
    UriMatcher matcher =  new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "dictionary", SEARCH_WORDS);
    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "dictionary/#", GET_WORD);
    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY, SEARCH_SUGGEST);
    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY + "/*", SEARCH_SUGGEST);

    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_SHORTCUT, REFRESH_SHORTCUT);
    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_SHORTCUT + "/*", REFRESH_SHORTCUT);
    return matcher;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    mDictionary = new DictionaryDatabase(getContext());
    return true;
}

@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs,
                    String sortOrder) {

    switch (sURIMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case SEARCH_SUGGEST:
            if (selectionArgs == null) {
              throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                  "selectionArgs must be provided for the Uri: " + uri);
            }
            return getSuggestions(selectionArgs[0]);
        case SEARCH_WORDS:
            if (selectionArgs == null) {
              throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                  "selectionArgs must be provided for the Uri: " + uri);
            }
            return search(selectionArgs[0]);
        case GET_WORD:
            return getWord(uri);
        case REFRESH_SHORTCUT:
            return refreshShortcut(uri);
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown Uri: " + uri);
    }
}

private Cursor getSuggestions(String query) {
  query = query.toLowerCase();
  String[] columns = new String[] {
      BaseColumns._ID,
      DictionaryDatabase.KEY_WORD,
      SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID};

  return mDictionary.getWordMatches(query, columns);
}

private Cursor search(String query) {
  query = query.toLowerCase();
  String[] columns = new String[] {
      BaseColumns._ID,
      DictionaryDatabase.KEY_WORD,
      DictionaryDatabase.KEY_DEFINITION};

  return mDictionary.getWordMatches(query, columns);
}

private Cursor getWord(Uri uri) {
  String rowId = uri.getLastPathSegment();
  String[] columns = new String[] {
      DictionaryDatabase.KEY_WORD,
      DictionaryDatabase.KEY_DEFINITION};

  return mDictionary.getWord(rowId, columns);
}

private Cursor refreshShortcut(Uri uri) {

  String rowId = uri.getLastPathSegment();
  String[] columns = new String[] {
      BaseColumns._ID,
      DictionaryDatabase.KEY_WORD,
      DictionaryDatabase.KEY_DEFINITION,
      SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID,
      SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID};

  return mDictionary.getWord(rowId, columns);
}

@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
    switch (sURIMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case SEARCH_WORDS:
            return WORDS_MIME_TYPE;
        case GET_WORD:
            return DEFINITION_MIME_TYPE;
        case SEARCH_SUGGEST:
            return SearchManager.SUGGEST_MIME_TYPE;
        case REFRESH_SHORTCUT:
            return SearchManager.SHORTCUT_MIME_TYPE;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URL " + uri);
    }
}

@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}

@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}

@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}

}
```

SenseDictionary.java

```
public class SenseDictionary extends Activity {

private TextView mTextView;
private ListView mListView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    handleIntent(getIntent());
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    handleIntent(intent);
}

private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Intent wordIntent = new Intent(this, WordActivity.class);
        wordIntent.setData(intent.getData());
        startActivity(wordIntent);
    } else if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        showResults(query);
    }
}

private void showResults(String query) {

    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(DictionaryProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
                            new String[] {query}, null);

    if (cursor == null) {
        mTextView.setText(getString(R.string.no_results, new Object[] {query}));
    } else {
        int count = cursor.getCount();
        String countString = getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.search_results,
                                count, new Object[] {count, query});
        mTextView.setText(countString);

        String[] from = new String[] { DictionaryDatabase.KEY_WORD,
                                       DictionaryDatabase.KEY_DEFINITION };

        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.word,
                               R.id.definition };

        SimpleCursorAdapter words = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                                      R.layout.result, cursor, from, to);
        mListView.setAdapter(words);

        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent wordIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WordActivity.class);
                Uri data = Uri.withAppendedPath(DictionaryProvider.CONTENT_URI,
                                                String.valueOf(id));
                wordIntent.setData(data);
                startActivity(wordIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.search:
            onSearchRequested();
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

}

WordActivity.java

```
package com.pesquisa.dicionario.searchabledict;



import com.pesquisa.dicionario.searchabledict.R;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.ActionBar;
 import android.app.SearchManager;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.database.Cursor;
 import android.net.Uri;
 import android.os.Build;
 import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.SearchView;
 import android.widget.TextView;

public class WordActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.word);

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor == null) {
        finish();
    } else {
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        TextView word = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.word);
        TextView definition = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.definition);

        int wIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DictionaryDatabase.KEY_WORD);
        int dIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DictionaryDatabase.KEY_DEFINITION);

        word.setText(cursor.getString(wIndex));
        definition.setText(cursor.getString(dIndex));
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.search:
            onSearchRequested();
            return true;
        case android.R.id.home:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SenseDictionary.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
}
```

LAYOUTS

main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/intro">

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/text"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@drawable/fundo"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:text="@string/search_instructions"
     android:textColor="?android:textColorPrimary"
     android:textSize="17sp" />

<ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
```

result.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="#ffffff">
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/word"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:background="#ffffff"/>
```

word.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical">

  <LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/word"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:textColor="?android:textColorPrimary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/definition"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:textColor="#ff0000"
    android:textSize="18dp" />



   </LinearLayout>

   </ScrollView>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.pesquisa.dicionario.searchabledict"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon2"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.pesquisa.dicionario.searchabledict.SenseDictionary"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                   android:resource="@xml/searchable" />

    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.pesquisa.dicionario.searchabledict.WordActivity" />

    <provider android:name="com.pesquisa.dicionario.searchabledict.DictionaryProvider"
              android:authorities="com.pesquisa.dicionario.searchabledict.DictionaryProvider" />

    <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
               android:value=".SenseDictionary" />


</application>
```

Comment: You added much source code but we need your logcat, without it it's pretty hard to help you.

Comment: Please don't throw all code you have at us! reduce it to the necessary parts and add your logcat output!

Comment: Oh and the code you post shouldn't even compile! Check the last few lines of your SenseDictionary.java, total mess up..

Comment: Sorry, guys, I just did that because I would like to help everybody understand the real problem easier. I'll put my logcat now. Just a second.

Comment: WarrenFaith, what's wrong with the last few lines oy my SenseDictionary.java? I didn't understand. I'm newbie. Could you help me? Because the application works perfectly on android 2.2, 3.0...tablet...not Jelly Bean :/

Comment: @FotogênicasBrasil you have the `@Override` annotation with no function below it. You have superfluous return statements. And there appear to be too many closing brackets. As it is written here this code should not compile.

Comment: Let me correct this!!!

Comment: @FoamyGuy So, I edited the SenseActivity.java, I pasted it wrongly. But, my application still doesn't work yet.

Comment: did you consider checking `at com.pesquisa.dicionario.searchabledict.WordActivity.onCreate(WordActivity.java:30)` for what could be null there ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [getActionBar() returns null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867076/getactionbar-returns-null)

Comment: duplicate, please close. bottom line is, getActionBar() returns null if title is not shown.

Comment: @njzk2 Sorry, I didn't understand. I'm more visual. Could you type the code for me, please? As everybody does here in other posts. Thanks in advance!!! Please!!!

Comment: this question is a duplicate, as I indicated. follow the link to that other question.

Comment: (also, put more simply : `FEATURE_NO_TITLE` => `getActionBar() == null` => your issue)