# java.lang.NullPointerException trying to enable action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button

Tags: java, android

This one thing is holding me back.. the app crashes as soon as it it launched, logcat points to the following causing the issue (2nd line down):

```
    // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }
    }
```

Logcat:

```
12-11 01:25:51.852  10780-10780/com.example.paul.amityhealth W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41979c98)
12-11 01:25:51.852  10780-10780/com.example.paul.amityhealth W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: uncaught exception occurred
12-11 01:25:51.853  10780-10780/com.example.paul.amityhealth W/System.err﹕ java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.paul.amityhealth/com.example.paul.amityhealth.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-11 01:25:51.855  10780-10780/com.example.paul.amityhealth W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
12-11 01:25:51.856  10780-10780/com.example.paul.amityhealth W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2410)
12-11 01:25:51.857  10780-10780/com.example.paul.amityhealth W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
12-11 01:25:51.858  10780-10780/com.example.paul.amityhealth W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331)
12-11 01:25:51.859  10780-10780/com.example.paul.amityhealth W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
12-11 01:25:51.860  10780-10780/com.example.paul.amityhealth W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
12-11 01:25:51.860  10780-10780/com.example.paul.amityhealth W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5388)
12-11 01:25:51.861  10780-10780/com.example.paul.amityhealth W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-11 01:25:51.862  10780-10780/com.example.paul.amityhealth W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-11 01:25:51.863  10780-10780/com.example.paul.amityhealth W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-11 01:25:51.863  10780-10780/com.example.paul.amityhealth W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:655)
12-11 01:25:51.865  10780-10780/com.example.paul.amityhealth W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-11 01:25:51.866  10780-10780/com.example.paul.amityhealth W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-11 01:25:51.868  10780-10780/com.example.paul.amityhealth W/System.err﹕ at com.example.paul.amityhealth.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:86)
12-11 01:25:51.869  10780-10780/com.example.paul.amityhealth W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5280)
12-11 01:25:51.870  10780-10780/com.example.paul.amityhealth W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
12-11 01:25:51.871  10780-10780/com.example.paul.amityhealth W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2322)
12-11 01:25:51.872  10780-10780/com.example.paul.amityhealth W/System.err﹕ ... 11 more
12-11 01:25:51.872  10780-10780/com.example.paul.amityhealth W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: calling UncaughtExceptionHandler
12-11 01:25:51.884  10780-10780/com.example.paul.amityhealth E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.paul.amityhealth, PID: 10780
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.paul.amityhealth/com.example.paul.amityhealth.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2410)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5388)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:655)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.paul.amityhealth.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:86)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5280)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2322)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2410)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5388)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:655)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have tried changing to false, doesnt work either. Even ridding of the 2 lines is not helping, I can't find an answer. Im a relatively new dev so if you answer make it simple to understand, cheers!

Edit: After adding the breakpoint, this is shown:

```
this = {com.example.paul.amityhealth.MainActivity@830043175400}
savedInstanceState = null
mDrawerList = {android.widget.ListView@830043260048}"android.widget.ListView{426f0490 VFED.VC. ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f090041 app:id/list_slidermenu}"
adapter = {com.example.paul.amityhealth.NavDrawerListAdapter@830043274344}
mDrawerToggle = null
```

Solved:

I added the following to manifest file:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
```

Thanks for the support!

Comment: Have you tried to set a breakpoint in getActionBar()? It sounds like it is returning `null`.

Comment: added to the top line of the code. you were right, it is 'null'

Comment: I am totally lost as to how to fix this. :(

Comment: This might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867076/getactionbar-returns-null

Have you looked there?

Comment: Let me have a look, ill get back to you after

Comment: `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` is what i am using..

Comment: Solved. Thank you. See edit to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's bug, maybe not, but my friend got same problem when he started his adventure with Android development few days ago. **com.example** was a cause

Change your package, rebuild and clean project. If this does not help, create a new project just without the beginning in package name.

And check your *res/values/styles.xml* file, maybe you disable actionbar in it.
Should be

```
<item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
<item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
```

Comment: 'code' <resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
'code'