# Android java.lang.NullPointerException getActionBar()

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I tried to implement an Setting Activity class but it give's me back an error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.andrei.sunshine.SettingsActivity.setupActionBar(SettingsActivity.java:58)
            at com.example.andrei.sunshine.SettingsActivity.onCreate(SettingsActivity.java:48)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
```

This is the line :  `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`

And the AndroidManifest is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DetailActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_detail"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.andrei.sunshine.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.andrei.sunshine.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

Please help me

Comment: Show your activity code.

Comment: Probably `getActionBar()` is returning null

Comment: possible duplicate of [getActionBar() returns null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867076/getactionbar-returns-null)

Comment: class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

Comment: @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setupActionBar();
    }

Comment: @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    private void setupActionBar() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            // Show the Up button in the action bar.
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

Comment: How to comment with blocks of code ?

Answer (score 2):

If your `SettingsActivity` extend `ActionBarActivity`, your `getActionBar();` will be available.

```
public class SettingsActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.yourLayout);
        //If you use support library
        //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); 
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html#getSupportActionBar%28%29) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You should check this reference http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

If you are supporting API levels lower than 11:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar
```

If supporting only API level 11 and higher:

```
import android.app.ActionBar
```

Instead of using getActionBar, use  getSupportActionBar

Answer (score 0):

It can happen if your theme is NoTitleBar or NoActionBar, or if you call `getActionBar()` before `setContentView(R.layout.layout);`

Answer (score 0):

Try to change it getSupportActionBar() if you are using appcompact ActionbarActivity