# Android Studio 1.0.2: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, runtime

Here is the error:

```
02-14 02:00:55.663      907-907/com.wlodsgn.bunbunup E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.wlodsgn.bunbunup, PID: 907
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.wlodsgn.bunbunup/com.wlodsgn.bunbunup.MenuActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.wlodsgn.bunbunup.MenuActivity.onCreate(MenuActivity.java:81)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    02-14 02:01:01.643      907-907/com.wlodsgn.bunbunup I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 907 SIG: 9
```

I seriously have no idea what might be the problem, spent couple of hours trying to look for a solution but it is still crashing. The idea is to make my first main activity (IntroActivity.java) open another activity(menuactivity.java) with navigation drawer. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is IntroActivity.java:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

/**
 * Created by WiLo on 2/13/2015.
 */
public class IntroActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_intro);
        Log.i("BunBunUp", "MainActivity Created");
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_intro, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void startMenuActivity(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(IntroActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        Log.i("BunBunUp", "IntroActivity Resumed");
    }

    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        Log.i("BunBunUp", "IntroActivity Paused");
    }

    protected void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        Log.i("BunBunUp", "IntroActivity Stopped");
    }
}
```

Here is MenuActivity.java:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

/**
 * Created by WiLo on 2/13/2015.
 */
public class MenuActivity extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // agregar un nuevo item al menu deslizante
        // Favoritos
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Pedidos
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Catologo
        //navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1), true, "Estrenos"));
        // Contacto
        //navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));

        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* *
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new FmMenu();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new FmContacto();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("Ramiro", "MainActivity - Error cuando se creo el fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
```

**In Response to Simon's question, here is my debug result:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLM2Q.jpg

**And these are the variable results:**

```
this = {com.wlodsgn.bunbunup.MenuActivity@831912707472}
adapter = {com.wlodsgn.bunbunup.NavDrawerListAdapter@831912476752}
mDrawerLayout = {android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout@831912722552}"android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout{b1dcc078 VFE..... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f090042 app:id/drawer_layout}"
mDrawerList = {android.widget.ListView@831912773352}"android.widget.ListView{b1dd86e8 VFED.VC. ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f090044 app:id/list_slidermenu}"
mDrawerTitle = {java.lang.String@831912705496}"Menu"
mDrawerToggle = null
mTitle = {java.lang.String@831912705496}"Menu"
navDrawerItems = {java.util.ArrayList@831912670472} size = 2
navMenuIcons = {android.content.res.TypedArray@831912712688}"[3, 77, 2, 2130837561, 0, 160, 3, 73, 2, 2130837559, 0, 160, 3, 72, 2, 2130837560, 0, 160, 3, 76, 2, 2130837556, 0, 160, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, ...
navMenuTitles = {java.lang.String[4]@831912431488}
mActionBar = null
mActivityInfo = {android.content.pm.ActivityInfo@831912705176}"ActivityInfo{b1dc7c98 com.wlodsgn.bunbunup.MenuActivity}"
mAllLoaderManagers = null
mApplication = {android.app.Application@831912467056}
mWindowManager = {android.view.WindowManagerImpl@831912710184}
mWindow = {com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow@831912708664}
mUiThread = {java.lang.Thread@831908953256}"Thread[main,5,main]"
mTranslucentCallback = null
mComponent = {android.content.ComponentName@831912704936}"ComponentInfo{com.wlodsgn.bunbunup/com.wlodsgn.bunbunup.MenuActivity}"
mToken = {android.os.BinderProxy@831912705080}
mContainer = {android.app.Activity$1@831912707880}
mCurrentConfig = {android.content.res.Configuration@831912708528}"{1.0 310mcc260mnc en_US ldltr sw360dp w360dp h567dp 480dpi nrml port finger qwerty/v/v -nav/h s.5}"
mDecor = null
mTitle = {java.lang.String@831912705496}"Menu"
mDefaultKeySsb = null
mSearchManager = null
mResultData = null
mEmbeddedID = null
mParent = null
mMenuInflater = null
mFragments = {android.app.FragmentManagerImpl@831912707760}"FragmentManager{b1dc86b0 in MenuActivity{b1dc8590}}"
mHandler = {android.os.Handler@831912708008}"Handler (android.os.Handler) {b1dc87a8}"
mManagedDialogs = null
mInstanceTracker = {android.os.StrictMode$InstanceTracker@831912707920}
mInstrumentation = {android.app.Instrumentation@831912463176}
mIntent = {android.content.Intent@831912704784}"Intent { cmp=com.wlodsgn.bunbunup/.MenuActivity }"
mLastNonConfigurationInstances = null
mLoaderManager = null
mManagedCursors = {java.util.ArrayList@831912707896} size = 0
mMainThread = {android.app.ActivityThread@831912436760}
mLoadersStarted = false
mIdent = -1308749784
mFinished = false
mEnableDefaultActionBarUp = false
mResultCode = 0
mDoReportFullyDrawn = true
mResumed = false
mDestroyed = false
mStartedActivity = false
mStopped = false
mTemporaryPause = false
mDefaultKeyMode = 0
mTitleColor = 0
mTitleReady = false
mConfigChangeFlags = 0
mCheckedForLoaderManager = false
mChangingConfigurations = false
mVisibleFromClient = true
mVisibleFromServer = false
mChangeCanvasToTranslucent = false
mWindowAdded = false
mCalled = true
mBase = {android.app.ContextImpl@831912708040}
mInflater = {com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater@831912709768}
mOverrideConfiguration = null
mResources = {android.content.res.Resources@831912458488}
mTheme = {android.content.res.Resources$Theme@831912710208}
mThemeResource = 2131492864
mBase = {android.app.ContextImpl@831912708040}
savedInstanceState = null
mDrawerList = {android.widget.ListView@831912773352}"android.widget.ListView{b1dd86e8 VFED.VC. ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f090044 app:id/list_slidermenu}"
mTempRect = {android.graphics.Rect@831912490576}"Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0)"
mArrowScrollFocusResult = {android.widget.ListView$ArrowScrollFocusResult@831912688680}
mDivider = {android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable@831912513672}
mOverScrollHeader = null
mOverScrollFooter = null
mDividerPaint = null
mFocusSelector = null
mHeaderViewInfos = {java.util.ArrayList@831912694584} size = 0
mFooterViewInfos = {java.util.ArrayList@831912689696} size = 0
mHeaderDividersEnabled = true
mFooterDividersEnabled = true
mIsCacheColorOpaque = false
mItemsCanFocus = false
mDividerIsOpaque = true
mDividerHeight = 3
mAreAllItemsSelectable = true
mAccessibilityDelegate = null
mVelocityTracker = null
mAdapter = {com.wlodsgn.bunbunup.NavDrawerListAdapter@831912476752}
mTouchModeReset = null
mTouchFrame = null
mTextFilter = null
mSelectorRect = {android.graphics.Rect@831912543968}"Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0)"
mCheckStates = {android.util.SparseBooleanArray@831912575600}"{}"
mCheckedIdStates = null
mSelector = {android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable@831912745608}
mChoiceActionMode = null
mScrollUp = null
mClearScrollingCache = null
mContextMenuInfo = null
mDataSetObserver = {android.widget.AbsListView$AdapterDataSetObserver@831912473520}
mDefInputConnection = null
mScrollStrictSpan = null
mScrollDown = null
mRemoteAdapter = null
mRecycler = {android.widget.AbsListView$RecycleBin@831912464376}
mEdgeGlowBottom = {android.widget.EdgeEffect@831912768272}
mEdgeGlowTop = {android.widget.EdgeEffect@831912774568}
mPublicInputConnection = null
mPositionScroller = null
mFastScroller = null
mPositionScrollAfterLayout = null
mPopup = null
mPerformClick = null
mFlingRunnable = null
mFlingStrictSpan = null
mPendingSync = null
mPendingCheckForTap = null
mPendingCheckForLongPress = null
mPendingCheckForKeyLongPress = null
mOwnerThread = {java.lang.Thread@831908953256}"Thread[main,5,main]"
mIsScrap = {boolean[1]@831912700520}
mOnScrollListener = null
mMultiChoiceModeCallback = null
mListPadding = {android.graphics.Rect@831912509624}"Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0)"
mLastPositionDistanceGuess = 0
mLastScrollState = 0
mLastTouchMode = -1
mLastY = 0
mLayoutMode = 0
mLastHandledItemCount = 0
mMaximumVelocity = 24000
mMinimumVelocity = 150
mMotionCorrection = 0
mMotionPosition = 0
mMotionViewNewTop = 0
mMotionViewOriginalTop = 0
mMotionX = 0
mMotionY = 0
mLastAccessibilityScrollEventToIndex = 0
mLastAccessibilityScrollEventFromIndex = 0
mOverflingDistance = 18
mOverscrollDistance = 0
mOverscrollMax = 0
mIsChildViewEnabled = false
mGlowPaddingRight = 0
mGlowPaddingLeft = 0
mGlobalLayoutListenerAddedFilter = false
mForceTranscriptScroll = false
mFlingProfilingStarted = false
mFirstPositionDistanceGuess = 0
mPopupHidden = false
mFiltered = false
mFastScrollEnabled = false
mFastScrollAlwaysVisible = false
mDrawSelectorOnTop = false
mDirection = 0
mResurrectToPosition = -1
mDensityScale = 3.0
mScrollProfilingStarted = false
mDeferNotifyDataSetChanged = false
mChoiceMode = 1
mScrollingCacheEnabled = true
mSelectedTop = 0
mSelectionBottomPadding = 0
mSelectionLeftPadding = 0
mSelectionRightPadding = 0
mSelectionTopPadding = 0
mCheckedItemCount = 0
mSelectorPosition = -1
mCachingStarted = false
mSmoothScrollbarEnabled = true
mStackFromBottom = false
mCachingActive = false
mTextFilterEnabled = false
mCacheColorHint = 0
mTouchMode = -1
mAdapterHasStableIds = false
mTouchSlop = 24
mTranscriptMode = 0
mVelocityScale = 1.0
mActivePointerId = -1
mWidthMeasureSpec = 0
mSelectionNotifier = null
mOnItemSelectedListener = null
mOnItemLongClickListener = null
mOnItemClickListener = {com.wlodsgn.bunbunup.MenuActivity$SlideMenuClickListener@831912422512}
mEmptyView = null
mSyncRowId = -9223372036854775808
mSyncHeight = 0
mSelectedRowId = -9223372036854775808
mOldSelectedRowId = -9223372036854775808
mNextSelectedRowId = -9223372036854775808
mNextSelectedPosition = -1
mNeedSync = false
mOldItemCount = 0
mOldSelectedPosition = -1
mLayoutHeight = 0
mDesiredFocusableState = true
mDesiredFocusableInTouchModeState = true
mDataChanged = false
mSelectedPosition = -1
mItemCount = 2
mBlockLayoutRequests = false
mSpecificTop = 0
mInLayout = false
mSyncMode = 0
mSyncPosition = 0
mFirstPosition = 0
mAnimationListener = null
mCachePaint = null
mVisibilityChangingChildren = null
mTransitioningViews = null
mChildTransformation = null
mChildren = {android.view.View[12]@831912500288}
mTransition = null
mCurrentDrag = null
mCurrentDragView = null
mDisappearingChildren = null
mDragNotifiedChildren = null
mFirstHoverTarget = null
mFirstTouchTarget = null
mFocused = null
mOnHierarchyChangeListener = null
mLocalPoint = null
mInvalidateRegion = null
mInvalidationTransformation = null
mLayoutTransitionListener = {android.view.ViewGroup$3@831912441104}
mLayoutAnimationController = null
mLastTouchDownX = 0.0
mLastTouchDownTime = 0
mLastTouchDownY = 0.0
mLayoutCalledWhileSuppressed = false
mLayoutMode = -1
mLastTouchDownIndex = -1
mHoveredSelf = false
mGroupFlags = 2228307
mPersistentDrawingCache = 2
mSuppressLayout = false
mChildrenCount = 0
mChildCountWithTransientState = 0
mChildAcceptsDrag = false
mUnsetPressedState = null
mAccessibilityDelegate = null
mUnscaledDrawingCache = null
mAnimator = null
mAttachInfo = null
mBackground = {android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable@831912688536}
mTransformationInfo = null
mTouchDelegate = null
mTag = null
mSendViewStateChangedAccessibilityEvent = null
mClipBounds = null
mContentDescription = null
mContext = {com.wlodsgn.bunbunup.MenuActivity@831912707472}
mCurrentAnimation = null
mDisplayList = null
mDrawableState = null
mDrawingCache = null
mSendViewScrolledAccessibilityEvent = null
mFloatingTreeObserver = null
mHardwareLayer = null
mScrollCache = {android.view.View$ScrollabilityCache@831912606240}
mResources = {android.content.res.Resources@831912458488}
mInputEventConsistencyVerifier = {android.view.InputEventConsistencyVerifier@831912774440}
mKeyedTags = null
mPerformClick = null
mPendingCheckForTap = null
mLayerPaint = null
mPendingCheckForLongPress = null
mLayoutInsets = null
mLayoutParams = {android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams@831912431416}
mParent = {android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout@831912722552}"android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout{b1dcc078 VFE..... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f090042 app:id/drawer_layout}"
mOverlay = null
mListenerInfo = null
mLocalDirtyRect = null
mMatchIdPredicate = null
mMatchLabelForPredicate = null
mMeasureCache = null
mMeasuredHeight = 0
mMeasuredWidth = 0
mMinHeight = 0
mMinWidth = 0
mNextFocusDownId = -1
mNextFocusForwardId = -1
mNextFocusLeftId = -1
mNextFocusRightId = -1
mNextFocusUpId = -1
mOldHeightMeasureSpec = -2147483648
mOldWidthMeasureSpec = -2147483648
mOverScrollMode = 1
mLeftPaddingDefined = false
mPaddingBottom = 0
mPaddingLeft = 0
mPaddingRight = 0
mPaddingTop = 0
mLeft = 0
mLayerType = 0
mLastIsOpaque = false
mLabelForId = -1
mPrivateFlags = -2121789184
mPrivateFlags2 = 4334600
mPrivateFlags3 = 0
mRecreateDisplayList = false
mID = 2131296324
mRight = 0
mRightPaddingDefined = false
mHasPerformedLongPress = false
mScrollX = 0
mScrollY = 0
mDrawingCacheBackgroundColor = 0
mCachingFailed = false
mSendingHoverAccessibilityEvents = false
mSystemUiVisibility = 0
mBottom = 0
mTop = 0
mBackgroundSizeChanged = true
mTouchSlop = 24
mBackgroundResource = 0
mTransientStateCount = 0
mAccessibilityViewId = -1
mAccessibilityCursorPosition = -1
mUserPaddingBottom = 0
mUserPaddingEnd = -2147483648
mUserPaddingLeft = 0
mUserPaddingLeftInitial = 0
mUserPaddingRight = 0
mUserPaddingRightInitial = 0
mUserPaddingStart = -2147483648
mVerticalScrollFactor = 0.0
mVerticalScrollbarPosition = 0
mViewFlags = 402932225
mWindowAttachCount = 0
adapter = {com.wlodsgn.bunbunup.NavDrawerListAdapter@831912476752}
context = {android.app.Application@831912467056}
navDrawerItems = {java.util.ArrayList@831912670472} size = 2
mDataSetObservable = {android.database.DataSetObservable@831912431560}
mDrawerToggle = null
```

**Now, when I do the step over, these are the results:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJ5ET.jpg

**Debug with variable after doing STEPOVER results posted in the comment section since they don't let me add more than 2 links.**

**If you need info from the subvariables in the debug, let me know**

***As for goonerandroid's request, here is my styles.xml code:***

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: Wich line is line 81 in your `MenuActivity`?

Comment: It's right there in the stack trace `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.wlodsgn.bunbunup.MenuActivity.onCreate(MenuActivity.java:81)` what is line 81?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Jens and Simon, line 81 is:

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

Comment: So, only getActionBar() can be the problem, so that method is returning null.  Why don't you step through your code with the debugger?  [You might find this useful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867076/getactionbar-returns-null)

Comment: it is something related to the theme you are applying for your activity.Post your styles.xml and will help you out

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, had to take a nap since been working on this project into late hours. Simon, I updated my post with more info on the debug I did and here is the link of the debug result after doing a stepover: http://pastebin.com/XvmKAW1z

Comment: Also, I checked the link you sent me and correct if I am wrong, I already have setContenView() within onCreate(). Is there something I am missing?

Comment: goonerdroid, I updated my post with the styles.xml code you requested. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing your theme to this

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

and not the AppCompat Version.It basically depends on whch api you are targeting.If it less than 14 use

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

and in your activity call your actionbar using this

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help gooner! It actually worked without changing the getActionBar to getSupportActionBar. Is it necessary to change it? I mean when I do it, it displays an error saying that it cannot resolve method. Do I have to import "android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity" so it can work? And I assume I have to change the other getActionBar below that one since the error is present. (Check my MenuActivity.java in my OP)