# android title bar null pointer exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-titlebar

I know it is simple but I wasnt able to fix it.Tried many solution from SOF.com but none worked. I am trying to display a title for activity and throws NPE. Using API19 for testing.Below are the codes:

In the activity:

```
 public class DisplayImageActivity extends RootActivity {  
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        getActionBar().setTitle("Image Preview");
```

In the Manifest:

```
  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

  <activity
        android:name=".DisplayImageActivity"
        android:label="<  app name  >"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
```

In the style.xml:

```
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Finally, the logcat says:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.kittu.<> /com.example.kittu.<>.DisplayImageActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2334)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.kittu.<  >.DisplayImageActivity.onCreate(DisplayImageActivity.java:44)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
```

Comment: What do you have in your `DisplayImageActivity` at line `44`?

Comment: What class are you inheriting from ?

Comment: I guess `getActionbar()` returns null. See this [discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6867076/715593) for possible causes and solutions.

Comment: @Leonardo: inherits from Root Activity: public class DisplayImageActivity extends RootActivity

Comment: @Holmes: at Line 44: getActionBar().setTitle("Image Preview");

Comment: `RootActivity` inherits from ? That may be your problem, you are not inheriting from a class that contains an actionBar. And btw, I'd strongly suggest you using http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html and Toolbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### If you are using the support library, your activity needs to extend it

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
```

and use `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()`

Comment: is there a way to implement this by not using "AppCompatActivity". I wanna do it by extending just "Activity".Pls suggest

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using AppCompat, then you should use `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()`.

Change this:

```
getActionBar().setTitle("Image Preview");
```

to this:

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Image Preview");
```

Hope this helps :)