# Text Through over code in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-tabhost

The same code works in eclipse but doesn't work in Android Studio.
In Android Studio there is text through in many functions. Check Out in image in the link below  http://postimg.org/image/d4sdh9t71/

```
package com.example.kiit_time_table_hello.kiittimetable;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

ActionBar actionbar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    actionbar = getActionBar();
    actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText("Monday").setTabListener(this));
    actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText("Tuesday").setTabListener(this));
    actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText("Wednesday").setTabListener(this));
    actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText("Thursday").setTabListener(this));
    actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText("Friday").setTabListener(this));
    actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText("Saturday").setTabListener(this));
}


@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I applied the solution found in this topic: [getActionBar() returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867076/getactionbar-returns-null).
And it works fine here.

> You have to define window type as actionbar before activity render its view, so before calling setContentView() method use:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
```

PS: The ActionBar.TabListener is Deprecated:

> This interface was deprecated in API level 21.
>   Action bar navigation modes are deprecated and not supported by inline toolbar action bars. Consider using other [common navigation patterns](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

That is just showing you that the method or constant is deprecated.

Action bar tabs were deprecated in API 21:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS