# nullpointerexception at Action bar setDisplayShowHomeEnabled () in Android

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I create custom action bar I really don't  know where is my mistake.I have some problems while creating Custom action bar.

And showing the null pointer exception at the line = **mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);**

Here is my error log

```
07-29 16:19:20.180  32714-32714/com.example.tazeen.classnkk E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tazeen.classnkk/com.example.tazeen.classnkk.AllPosts_Page}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.tazeen.classnkk.AllPosts_Page.CustomActionBar(AllPosts_Page.java:37)
            at com.example.tazeen.classnkk.AllPosts_Page.onCreate(AllPosts_Page.java:28)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4466)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have try last 5 to 7 hours , but can not find any proper solution.Please help me.Thanks.

Here is my Activity code

```
public class AllPosts_Page extends Activity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.all_post);
        CustomActionBar();
    }
public void CustomActionBar()
    {
        android.app.ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar();
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

        View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_action_bar, null);
        TextView mTitleTextView = (TextView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        mTitleTextView.setText("All Post");


        ImageView imageButton = (ImageView) mCustomView
                .findViewById(R.id.imgLeftMenu);
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Refresh Clicked!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });


        mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    }
```

menifest file

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <activity
            android:name=".Splash_Screen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Login_Screen" />
        <activity
            android:name=".AllPosts_Page">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Filter_Page"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_filter__page"
            android:theme="@style/ListFont">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

style.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:height">5dp</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Comment: maybe show some code?

Comment: Thanks for the reply . I have post some code above ,

Comment: null pointer exception at the line = mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

Comment: your `mActionBar` is null. `getActionBar()` is the correct place to look for issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867076/getactionbar-returns-null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` so you should get your `ActionBar` by `getSupportActionBar()` method, not `getActionBar()`

if your extended `Activity` is from Android system then style is incorrect (AppCompat) and Activity gets some default styling without `ActionBar`, so `getActionBar()` return `null`

else if you want to use this AppCompat style it is applicable for `AppCompatActivity` (and then you use should `getSupportActionBar()`)

Comment: I dont understand what you saying ? Means where i have to change in my coding . Can you explain please.

Comment: but when i use this ActionBar mAct = getSupportActionBar(); InCompatible type required android.app.ActionBar and found: android.support.v7.app.ActionBar . And when import  android.app.ActionBar this then getSupportActionBar() does not get support.

Comment: Thanks it solves my problem. Thanks a lot. But my custom action bar is not set proper , it shows left and right side default action bar space .