# Get error in android sidebar create and fix this issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

```
package com.example.bulksms;

import java.util.ArrayList;


import com.example.bulksms.adapter.NavDrawerListAdapter;
import com.example.bulksms.model.NavDrawerItem;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import com.example.bulksms.R;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class Home extends Activity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_activity);

        //if TheradPolicy When app crash automatically.
        //StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build(); StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1), true, "22"));
        // Pages
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1), true, "50+"));


        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* *
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new PhotosFragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new CommunityFragment();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new PagesFragment();
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

}
```

# Error Code here #

```
 - 12-30 15:16:23.733: E/AndroidRuntime(2814): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   12-30 15:16:23.733: E/AndroidRuntime(2814): Process:
   com.example.bulksms, PID: 2814 12-30 15:16:23.733:
   E/AndroidRuntime(2814): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
   activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bulksms/com.example.bulksms.Home}:
   java.lang.NullPointerException 12-30 15:16:23.733:
   E/AndroidRuntime(2814): at
   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2367)
   12-30 15:16:23.733: E/AndroidRuntime(2814): at
   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2419)
   12-30 15:16:23.733: E/AndroidRuntime(2814): at
   android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 12-30
   15:16:23.733: E/AndroidRuntime(2814): at
   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342)
   12-30 15:16:23.733: E/AndroidRuntime(2814): at
   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 12-30
   15:16:23.733: E/AndroidRuntime(2814): at
   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 12-30 15:16:23.733:
   E/AndroidRuntime(2814): at
   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5323) 12-30
   15:16:23.733: E/AndroidRuntime(2814): at
   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 12-30
   15:16:23.733: E/AndroidRuntime(2814): at
   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 12-30 15:16:23.733:
   E/AndroidRuntime(2814): at
   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
   12-30 15:16:23.733: E/AndroidRuntime(2814): at
   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644) 12-30
   15:16:23.733: E/AndroidRuntime(2814): at
   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 12-30 15:16:23.733:
   E/AndroidRuntime(2814): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
   12-30 15:16:23.733: E/AndroidRuntime(2814): at
   com.example.bulksms.Home.onCreate(Home.java:97) 12-30 15:16:23.733:
   E/AndroidRuntime(2814): at
   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5343) 12-30
   15:16:23.733: E/AndroidRuntime(2814): at
   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
   12-30 15:16:23.733: E/AndroidRuntime(2814): at
   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2331)
   12-30 15:16:23.733: E/AndroidRuntime(2814): ... 11 more
```

Comment: Getting above error in

Comment: Please, edit your question and format your code to be more readable. It will be easier for people here to help you with your problem. From what I can see, there is a NullPointerException on line 97 of Home.java file. Could you tell us what is in that specific line?

Comment: getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

Comment: Ok, it looks like ActionBar is not available in your example. Take a look at those answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867076/getactionbar-returns-null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace  getActionBar  TO getSupportActionBar also 
 Activity to ActionBarActivity and 
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;