# Android Application Name Appears as horizantal tool bar on the top of each activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, sdk

[image]**I am getting the application name on the top of each activity, which I do not want .**

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="24" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
     <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Login"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
```

> while removing `android:label="@string/app_name"` this i am still getting the app name on each activity as the pakage name of the app.

also tried with `<intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>`this .

tried all the following answers on the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397405/android-application-name-appears-as-activity-name)

**But still getting the app name on each and every activity .**

Comment: check the screenshot plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class UserProfile extends Activity {

ImageView profilePic;
EditText address_up;
Button update_up, exit_up;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle abc) {
    super.onCreate(abc);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.userprofile);
```

> **In activity class if you enter the code before setcontentview then action bar will disappear.`requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`**

Or else can create custom style as well.

**

Answer (score 1):

Create your own style and use it in style.xml. For example

```
<style name="YourTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="actionModeStyle">@style/SpeazieTheme.ActionMode</item>
    </style>
```

use it in your manifest file like this

replace

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

to

```
android:theme="@style/YourTheme"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a custom style in Manifest:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

Make sure that this style's parent is a `.NoTitleBar` theme, ie:

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Comment: Giving runtime error `\StudentDesk\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar'. `

Comment: Is your `Activity` extending `AppCompatActivity`? It should if you want to maintain compatibility with much of Android OS versions.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want any action bar then you can change in your value/style

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. such as -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or simply pick an existing android theme that hides the actionbar. 
For example: android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
You can either do throughout the whole app by setting the application style or only for selected activities.

Hope it helps.