# Android application label name appears everywhere

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am using this theme in my Android app, `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` in every activity my project name i.e the `label` name from the `Application` tag appears in every Android activity, before it was not happening but recently it is happening. If I remove the label then the package name appears instead of the title.

What exactly is happening ?

I know that there are several ways to fix it but show me where I am wrong and what is happening ? Is it a bug ?

I referred a previous answer [Android Application Name Appears as Activity Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397405/android-application-name-appears-as-activity-name) and tried but still did not work, So here is a copy of my manifest.xml

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Activity2"></activity>
    </application>
```

Below is a sample screenshot, the label name can be seen although that activity(Activity2) consists of a toolbar , the white area is a edittext in the toolbar and nothing else is present inside the toolbar.

**EDIT 1**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

**EDIT 2**

```
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {


    LinedEditText editText;
    Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity2);


        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        editText = (LinedEditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    }
}
```

**activity2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
  >
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/green"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
           android:id="@+id/title"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    <com.test.testproject.LinedEditText
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:gravity="top"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: you can set every Activitys separate labale.


<activity android:name=".Activity2"  android:label="@string/app_short_name"></activity>

Comment: That is fine..but I need to know the what exactly is the issue and why is it coming ? Is that a bug ?

Comment: i think by default every activity set app_name as a label.

Comment: post your style.xml...containing the theme..

Comment: @KuLdipPaTel Nope it never happened before.

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 Posted it.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

This is your problem. Avoid using Toolbar.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/green"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
           android:id="@+id/title"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

If you are using `NoActionBar` in your theme. Avoid using Toolbar in your Activity's layout. That is the reason you are getting the Activity name.

If you are using Toolbar make sure you disable the **TITLE** on it.

Comment: It never happened before  so now why is the question ?

Comment: are you using 26 API level ?

Comment: Current API level is 23.

Comment: Hope my answer make sense for your problem. Everything is fine from android side. its your code which is creating the problem.

Comment: Exactly where is what I would like to know ?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out.

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Comment: It never happened before so now why is the question ?

Comment: if you change your style.xml like this. <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>

Comment: You must do one of to. Code or XML

Answer (score 0):

```
Check with setting theme for specific activity..which solves your problem..try this 
<style name = "NoActionBar" parent = "@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name = "android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name = "android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Solution is fine ..I am looking for why is it happening now and not earlier ?

Answer (score 0):

Just put in onCreate() method after setSupportActionBar(toolbar).

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle("");
```

Comment: Solution is fine ..I am looking for why is it happening now and not earlier ? Is it a bug ?

Comment: have u change theme of application level?

Comment: `AppTheme` is the global theme

Comment: So did not changes in application theme item?

Comment: I just inherited from `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`