# Localization codes does not work

Tags: android, localization

I am developing an android app, and implementing localization.

Hence am creating strings.xml in seperate folders such as values, values-ja, values-es.

But, eclipse throws errors for my values folder.

values-es-US is not working for spanish US
values-fr-CA is not working  french Canada

I was referring to http://download1.parallels.com/SiteBuilder/Windows/docs/3.2/en_US/sitebulder-3.2-win-sdk-localization-pack-creation-guide/30801.htm for the localization codes

Other localizations such as values-hk,values-tw,values-uk seems to fine.

Can somebody point me to the right direction? How can i have separate strings for spanish US and Spain, French Canada and france.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please check out following codes given by the Android.

Locale Code     Language / Country
Default     English / United Kingdom de-rDE
de-rDE     =     German / Germany
fr-rFR     =     French / France
fr-rCA     =     French / Canada
en-rCA     =     English / Canada
ja-rJP     =     Japanese / Japan
en-rUS     =     English / United States

Comment: hi Anup, thanks, but was wondering, am doing in app localization by setting the locate, will these values work?

Comment: And anup, do you have any reference to the document from which you listed out the language codes?

Comment: setting the locale to fr-CA (Locale locale = new Locale("fr-CA")) while the values folder is set to values-fr-rCA. setting locale to "de" works though - any suggestions

Comment: yes certainly I have a ref doc http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/localization/index.html

Comment: I think you dont need to change locales explicitly since whenever you change the locale of the phone from phone settings your app automatically picks the appropriate values.

Comment: Thanks anup, i understand android can pickup the settings from the phone; but am looking to have an in-app language change without effecting anything else - it works for now :)

Answer (score 2):

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/locale/

Reading that document, i realized i can set the locale with  new Locale("fr","ca"); and changing the values folder to values-fr-rCA worked

Thanks