Where can I find the application name from APK?
I just want to extract an app name (not a package name) from APK (android).
But it seems there is no app name in manifest.
Is there any way to get an application name from the APK?
I just looked the AndroidManifes.xml but it is hard to find the app name.

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/5552027/150978
