# Android Change the app name and logo

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to android programming.I have started building an app using eclipse.In the layout file the app icon and App name comes there by default. How do I change it.
A relative layout is there by default.
Whatever I add say--image view textview get added below the main title bar.
How do I change this?

Comment: You need to read a bit on the basics of Android Development. Kindly check on the API demos and some tutorials on web.

Comment: you can change app name is manifest file, app logo can be replaced using create new icon set or replacing the current icon in the drawabe folder

Comment: You cannot change the manifest or the resource in the signed-and-sealed APK, except through a software upgrade.android:icon="@drawable/icon".Change the icon .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443304/how-to-change-an-android-apps-name. Have a look at the link.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Links to app name and icon are placed in the `AndroidManifest.xml` inside the `application` tag. String resources, like `@string/app_name`, are placed inside the `strings.xml` file in the `res/values` directory. Drawable resources, like `@drawable/ic_launcher`, are inside the `res/drawable` set of directories. Good luck!

Answer (score 8):

try This

For Logo
`android:icon="@drawable/icon"`

For Application Name  `android:label="@string/app_name"`

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out by *Egor*, you must change the appropriate string in your `strings.xml`. Typically, the key name in the `strings.xml` is by default `app_name`. Change this to whatever you wish to change your App's name to.

For your App's icon, I would recommend using this website to create the appropriate resources: http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-launcher.html. This saves the trouble of creating different size resources. It gives you all of them in on go. Once you have downloaded the new set of icons, just replace the old set of icons with the new set. Take care of the name though. Again, typically, the app icon has the name `ic_launcher`.

Comment: Thanx for the link..quite helpful

Comment: @Ciff: You are welcome. Besides the launcher icons, you will find a few other options there. They are useful too.

Answer (score 0):

Simply U have to change in Androidmanifest File in application tag which include property like For change logo use `android:icon="@drawable/icon"` property and change drawable image as per your requirement and for change application name  use  `android:label="@string/app_name"` property and write at string.xml file in app_name label put appropriate name for that.