# How to change the Android application icon in Worklight

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I read instructions [in this forum thread](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=448663) on how to change the application icon in Worklight, but it doesn't work. I get the following error:

> .../android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/aapt: /lib/libz.so.1: no version
>   information available (required by
>   /home/vernid/data/Development/WorkLight/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/aapt)
>
> .../android/native/AndroidManifest.xml:28: error: Error: String types
>   not allowed (at 'icon' with value 'icon.png').

any idea or example?

Many Thanks,
Dominique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application icon resides under the drawable folders. For example, in a Worklight project look under: yourAppName\android\native\res\drawable-*\icon.png. This is the icon you want to replace.

To replace the application icon:

1. Open the nativeResources folder: yourAppName\android\nativeResource\res
2. Each drawable folder in it represents a different screen density; you need to place your different icon.png files for each of the densities* you support in your application
3. After you have placed the images, build and deploy
4. Launch in emulator or device, you should now see the new icon

For more information about screen densities in Android, [see the online documentation for it](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Comment: Thanks Idan, I was wondering if I have to change the AndroidManifest or not, but apparently not.

Comment: @Idan Adar: how can i change the android application name i need to add space between my application name for android, i'll be able to change it in iphone ipad environment by changing name on plist file but don't know how to change it on android?

Comment: Do the change mentioned in the following question in apps\your-app\android\native\AndroidManifest.xml: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443304/how-to-change-an-android-apps-name