# Is there a way to change the name of an application on Google Play app store?

Tags: android, google-play

I submitted an app to the app store last year and I found out a few weeks ago the name is being used for something similar. Is there a way to change the name of the app?

**UPDATE**:
In AIR you an application has an application descriptor file. In the application descriptor file is the Android manifest.

In the application descriptor file change the name attribute (leave the id the same):

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.6">

    <id>com.mycompany.myAppID</id>
    <filename>MyApplicationFile</filename>
    <name>My Application Name</name>
```

**At first** I thought that you needed to change the "android:label" attribute on the application tag in the Android specific section as shown:

```
<android>
    <manifestAdditions><![CDATA[
        <manifest android:installLocation="auto">
            <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="12"/>
            <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>
            <application android:label="My Application Name"></application>
        </manifest>
    ]]></manifestAdditions>
</android>
```

But when I did that I would get an error, "error 404: Android attribute android:label is not allowed to be overridden". I'm guessing the AIR compiler is setting that attribute through the name property.

In Android on the device the name has been changed. However, I have yet to upload this to GooglePlay. I think I need to change the application product name there as well.

**UPDATE**
Answer: Change the name property.

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.6">

    <id>com.mycompany.myAppID</id>
    <filename>MyApplicationFile</filename>
    <name>Application Name Can Change</name>
```

You cannot change the ID as mentioned in an answer but you can change the name. I changed the name, created a new build, uploaded it to the Google app store and it has changed on the Google app store successfully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that all I had to do to change the name of the app is to change the name property in the application descriptor file.

Before:

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.6">

    <id>com.mycompany.myAppID</id>
    <filename>MyApplicationFile</filename>
    <name>My Application Name</name>

</application>
```

After:

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.6">

    <id>com.mycompany.myAppID</id>
    <filename>MyApplicationFile</filename>
    <name>My Shiny New Application Name</name>

</application>
```

I changed the name, created a new build and package, uploaded it to Google app store and published. I changed the name of the Google app store listing a few minutes after upload. When the app changes went live the app name was changed. The app may have been in draft mode but I think I published it on accident before changing the name in the store. Either way it's updated.

The app ID shows up in some locations and lists and there is nothing you can do AFAIK to change it after it has been submitted to some app stores except submit a new app with that ID.

Comment: Also, see the answer by @Paresh for native Android apps.

Answer (score 21):

Yes, you can change the name whenever you want by changing android:label attribute of your application tag in AndroidManifest.xml file.

**But, you can't change Package name once you uploaded app on play store.**

Comment: That's true. If you are writing an AIR app the package would be the ID tag in the application descriptor file. See the code in the update before the filename tag.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443304/how-to-change-an-android-apps-name) if you want to change your app name. Also you have to update your app on Google Play.

Comment: Thanks. In AIR we have a manifest file but it's slightly different than the Android one. I'll see if I can apply that knowledge in those posts to my application.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts you're welcome, let me know your solution when you finish!

Answer (score 1):

yes you can change, this is the answer i got from google support
me : can i change app name, app icon and description, after app is published
i mean the name appear on google play and icon
11:09 pm
Google play chat answer :
Yes, you can change your app details on the Main Store Listing page of your Play Console.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet so this is my answer.
You can't change the name of the package once you've uploaded the first APK.

You also can't remove an app from the store as far as I can see. You can only deactivate an APK and un-publish the store listing. As far as I can tell, you can't remove it to allow you to upload a package of the same name again o_0 - bit of a problem for me considering I misspelled my package name first time round :/

Comment: That's the way I understand it as well. You can change the name of your app but not the package name. So, "My App" can be renamed to "My Drawing App" but package name, "com.mycompany.MyApp" cannot be changed at all.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to re-upload your package. `All apps -> select app -> store presence -> store listing` and change the title