# Change icon/name of the app/author's name after publishing app on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, manifest, publish

I made an app and published it at Google Play.
Can I change icon/name of the app/author's name after publishing app on Google Play?

Comment: [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15720994/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-name-of-an-application-on-google-play-app-store)

Comment: Which icon/name you are talking about, in the application or on publisher account application page?

Comment: Icon of the app and name of the author of the app

Comment: Then you need to upload one more version with upgrading version name and version code..

Comment: And by author's name, I mean the developers name as seen under the name of my app on Google Play

Answer (score 1):

Changes for existing app is not allowed without re-submission.
You need to do the upgrade in manifest file with name,auther and version-name and version-code as well.Then re-submit the app at Google Play.

Check this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443304/how-to-change-an-android-apps-name), it might be of your interest.

Comment: Thanks. Can I just re-upload the app after name change or does the app have to be reviewed again by Google first?

Comment: Every submission will be reviewed by Google. Thought i personally don't find this as strict as that of Apple app store review process! :)

Comment: Thanks @Raushabh for your Edit. It was indeed a necessary part which i neglected.

Answer (score 1):

@Aditya has a good answer for changing the app icon, but you also asked about changing the developer name-

Yes, you can change this as well. Open up the Developer Console, then go to the settings tab. The first option is the developer name.

Be aware, however, that this will change the developer name for *all* of the apps published under that account.