# Error in Android Project Name

Tags: android

I have change the name of my project from "EAAS" to "Get Ambulance". It gave error in setContentView(R.layout.activity_login); The R was red lined so i clicked on it and imported R. package but then it gave error on activity_logic. so i changed my project name again to "Ambulance" the error in R.layout.activity_logic got solved. but now when i run my application on Emulator the name of the project is still "EAAS". its not changed. If anyone knows about these two issue please let me know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into your `strings.xml` file located in `res/values/` and change the `app_name` entry assuming your Android Manifest file is using app_name for the application name.

Comment: What about R.layout.activity_logic? This time when i changed my project name add the java files got error. In "R.layout.activity_logic" the R is underlined red. when i import .R library "activity_logic" got red.

Comment: I guess you imported `android.R`, remove it and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, the project name should not contain any spaces.

For the second - You can change the application name [in the manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443304/how-to-change-an-android-apps-name/5443324#5443324).

Comment: What about R.layout.activity_logic? This time when i changed my project name add the java files got error. In "R.layout.activity_logic" the R is underlined red. when i import .R library "activity_logic" got red.

Answer (score 0):

Application names cannot have any space in between.