# Is it advisable to change the name of an app after publishing it on Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app on Google Play named "Mathadict"

I wish to change its name to "Math Addict".

First of all isit advisable to do so? Because my apps have been suspended in the past and I am very apprehensive about it.

If yes then what are the things that should be kept in mind while doing so? For example I think I will have to change the app_name string value in strings.xml.

Also, how to check if a name is available for use?

Comment: Yes you can change the name, logo, but make sure there are no existing app with same name, logo on the play store

Comment: There is no app with such name on Google
Play but- 1. There's an app with the same
name on Apple App Store 2. A website with
the same name. Does this come under
Intellectual Property or Copyright?

Answer (score 4):

It's fine to change the name. What you really can't afford to do is to change the package name or the key that's used to sign the app. But there's no issue with changing the name.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can change your name of your application. No worries at all.

But remember Google could suspend the app because of some standard policy.

1. Using another logo which already exists.
2. Using the same name of an app that already exists in the Play store.

So beware of such things and publish your application.

Have a glance of this. https://play.google.com/about/developer-distribution-agreement.html

Comment: There is no app with such name on Google Play but-
1. There's an app with the same name on Apple App Store
2. A website with the same name

Does this comes under Intellectual Property or Copyright ?

Comment: no @RushilSablania apple playstore is totally different from google play and no relationship between the two. you can give same name for your ios and android app and publish in two different stores.

Answer (score 2):

Changes for existing app is not allowed without re-submission. You need to do the upgrade in manifest file with name,author and version-name and version-code as well.Then re-submit the app at Google Play. @[How to change an Android app's name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443304/how-to-change-an-android-apps-name)

Answer (score 1):

You can change the app's name, but you should keep in mind that something can not change once published. See [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html)