# Can I change my Android app icon and name in later release?

Tags: android, google-play, android-icons

This is going to sound stupid in a way, but I want to know if it is possible to change the application logo (icon) and Android name in my subsequent releases?

Say, today I push my app in the Android market, and tomorrow I want to change the logo/icon (I know I "should" not do this), but is it possible to do so? Also, what about the application name?

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, you can change the name and logo whenever you want by changing `android:label` and `android:logo` attribute of your application tag in `AndroidManifest.xml file`.

But, you can't change `Package` name once you uploaded app on play store.

Comment: You can change the Package but you shouldn't as it will clear the downloads, ratings etc metadata of past version on play store. Since Package is used to uniquely define your app on the play store and android system

Answer (score 52):

I got the same question and I asked this to android developer support, got their reply as below

You may update your icon displayed in Google Play by uploading the updated icon to the Store Listing tab of the Play Console.
However, once the app has been installed on a device, the icon will be displayed from the graphic assets of the APK as defined in the “android:icon=” manifest property. The icon that is displayed in the apps list in the Play Console is also taken from the APK.

To display a different icon, please update the icon image file in your APK. To find the location of the existing icon, you can use the manifest property or check your APK’s “res” folder.

So I got the icon updated at app store without submitting the app again (Note: I have already submitted with the icon change, so what I was looking to is how this can be reflected to App store icon). Please see screenshots attached for getting someone who is needy.

[image: Left tab]
[image: right tab]

Comment: This exactly what I was looking for. We know that package name can't be changed. The changes you make in Androidmanifest.xml doesn't appear in Play Store listing or App's page on Play store. Thanks, much appreciated.

Comment: Much appreciated ! Not easy to find this config.

Comment: i was looking in the releases all over the place and eventually gave up,. until i ran into this post, you really helped ^^

Comment: So if I understand correctly, if you change the name in the "Store listing" and also in the AndroidManifest.xml label attribute, the name in Store listing will override the one in the manifest? So that means you cannot have a name of your app in Google play apps, and another app name at the shortcut icon (after the user installs the app) ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can change the name by changing [android:label](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html) attribute of your application tag in AndroidManifest.xml. and also you can change the application icon, but i would recommend you to add the comment in *"Whats New"* regarding the new Application Icon when you upload the application.But, you can NOT change Package name once you uploaded app on play store.

Also take a look at this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443304/how-to-change-an-android-apps-name)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change Store listing on play store whenever you want and there is no limit for this. you can change and improve your listing in terms of Graphics and SEO improvements.

According to **Google Developer Distribution Agreement** you can change and Modify:

1. Application Name
2. Icon/ Screenshots
3. Graphics/ feature Graphic
4. Application Policy and agreements
5. Featured Video
6. ASO/ Keywords and description

There is no harm implementing these changes but this could take a while to implement changes depending on account health and your geographical location...

This is my application ([Play Store Link...](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tulip.weather)). I have released multiple versions and implemented major changes in each version.

I changed icon and graphics more than 5 times and improved ASO couple of times.
This not just improved my user experience but also increased daily installs.

Based on my experience I will recommend continuous changes for best application optimization. and I want to recommend targeting events like:

> Christmas and New year, Independence Day, Halloween update, etc...

These types of updates entertain users and increase engagements and also helpful to build trust with your users.

Comment: Start targeting upcoming events and run your campaigns in order to gain maximum advantage.

Comment: how long would it take for the store listing to update? I want it to be on sync with the app version release

Comment: The update process mostly takes 2 to 3 hours. But, due to covid-19, this can take up to 24 hours.