# Can I change the High res icon after release

Tags: android, google-play, icons

Can I change the application high res icon (512x512) after I published the app into PROD or ALPHA?

I haven't found any info on this so far in Android dev guides !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can. You can change it at any time. 
       android:label and android:logo attributes can be changed at any time from your manifest.xml

Also read this post. 
[Can I change my android app icon and name in later release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26093962/can-i-change-my-android-app-icon-and-name-in-later-release)

Comment: Yes, I got that, but I am thinking of the High res icon what you have to manually upload to Google Play, not what you put into the app itself. 
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Of course that's possible. You can edit the store page at any time