# My app changed name, probably because of activity laucher

Tags: android, android-studio, title, launcher

i am creating an app, called "Moises", its the name of the project, and i wanted to do a loading screen, like show an imagem for 5sec, i did it, and i named "LoadingScreen" to the activity. I needed it to start first, so in the manifest i put this activity has launcher, works just fine, but the app name changed to "LoadingScreen" instead of "Moises". Like when i am testing it in my phone the name of the app appears "LoadingScreen".
Can't i have one activity launcher different then main activity whithout changing the name?
How can i fix it ?

Comment: check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443304/how-to-change-an-android-apps-name

Comment: just it give the name you want to see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 labels in the manifest one is the android:name( app) and other you can have label for your each activity separately in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

You need go to Res->Values->Strings and change String name of Layout