# App name not shown

Tags: android

I've set the name of the app like this

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

And the value off the string it's correct but the name app shown is the name of the main activity...**MainActivity** instead of My App name

Comment: Where are you looking for the name? Where is it supposed to appear? Are you talking about the launcher or the ActionBar?

Comment: maybe this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443304/how-to-change-an-android-apps-name

Answer (score 1):

See the line in  `Activity` declaration

Remove this line if you don't want

```
 android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
```