# App name missing from the launcher

Tags: java, android, xml

The application name in the launcher is not showing and when i click in the application label in the manifset it shows me more than one resource which they come from other libraries i used like meterial-about please help it's a very strange problem ...

**Manifest Picture**
[image]

**Launcher Picture** 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In java, the name of your application follows what you define `android:label` as... And you have it set to "", at least in the screenshot you give.

See this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443304/how-to-change-an-android-apps-name) for more information.

Comment: thank you for your response but i didn't set to empty "" but i set a value to it in values.xml

Comment: Did you try setting it in both locations?

Comment: yes i did the strange thing is that those values are from other libraries like AVLoadingIndicator or Material about .. still i changed them all with no result