# Published App Showing Default Icon & Name + Showing Full Lenght Name

Tags: android, google-play

I published App in play store. In this procedure, I gave my icon & name. When I search my App in play store, it is showing correct icon + name  but when I install it in my phone it is showing default android icon and package name.

[image: my app]
Where is the issue?

Second question: I want to show App short name in phone(after installation). 
like these show in picture:

[image: other apps]

Answer (score 0):

Those are part of your apk and not defined in play store.

You need to specify an icon drawable and a label in your android manifest xml. You should also specify the label for a launcher activity.

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/myicon" android:label="@string/shortname">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/shortname" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
...
```

Comment: Q#1: now icon is showing. what is better drawable or mipmap?    Q#2:shortname is showing in installing process but when installation complete then icon appear on phone is showing as Package name. What I do now?

Comment: @mirza mipmap is better

Comment: shortname is showing in installing process but when installation complete then icon appear on phone is showing as Package name not short. Please help me.

Comment: @mirza Add an attribute label to a launcher activity (the first one launched). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13200774/135837