# How can I change app icon position of ActionBar in API-21?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, appcompatactivity

I am trying to change app icon position of `actionBar` to left side, I am not using `toolbar` here, and I am using API 21 AppCompatActivity.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

    <!--Action bar style-->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleText</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleText</item>
    <item name="height">43dp</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">30dp</item>
    <item name="android:maxWidth">48dp</item>
    <item name="android:width">10dp</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleText" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textSize">17dp</item>
</style>
```

How can I change app name and icon position here?

Comment: Why aren't you using a Toolbar? It does the exact same thing and it's easily customizable

Comment: Actually i created this app for kitkat versions but most of peoples are now on lollipop and greater versions that's why i upgraded to api 21 and allmost all work is completed just that app icon is misplaced.

Comment: Use AppCompactActivity's Toolbar and add an Imageview inside it which will have your icon

Comment: So there is no any way to solve my issue?

Comment: I have to make so many changes now :(

Comment: It's only like four lines of code. Just make your activity extend AppCompactActivity and add the Toolbar to the top of your layout. And don't forget to call setSupportActionbar and pass the Toolbar to it

Comment: Ok i will try thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can't change app icon and app name in style.xml file. You have to set app icon and app name in AndroidManifest.xml file.

android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"

[How to change an Android app's name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443304/how-to-change-an-android-apps-name)

Comment: I'm not asking about the app icon, I'm asking about the changing app icon position from actionbar