# Change android application name

Tags: android, android-studio

I just finished my first android app and generated an apk file to test on my phone. Then I realized I left the default "My Application" name when making the project. So the app is installed with the name "My application". How do I change the name of the app?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14216822/2147481

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go to your values property, then strings and you will be able change it.

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">My application</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to res -> values -> strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My application</string> //change this text with desired text
</resources>
```