# Application name correction

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I recently created a trial android app and uploaded it to the Play Store. The application works but there is a problem.

The application name looks like this when downloaded to the phone: app_name
How can i fix this like?: App Name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Edit the label in the Manifest, it should point to a String resource and that contains the App Name.

See here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5443324/7968986