# How to change the name with which the application is installed on the phone

Tags: android, android-studio

I wanted to know if you can change the name with which the application is installed on the phone. The public name let's say.

I have tried to change the name of the folder, the package, and the one that appears in settings.gradle.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change an Android app's name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443304/how-to-change-an-android-apps-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By changing the `android:label` field in your application node in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

More detailed [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443304/how-to-change-an-android-apps-name?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).