# App Name is Eclipse MainActivity?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-emulator, android-activity

I have finished a tip calculator app, but when I run it the name is `MainActivity`, I don't know how to change it, I have tried editing `strings.xml` but when I run the app I get errors,I don't know what else to try, any suggestions for what I can do to change it so it appears on the emulator

on strings.xml...

name:`title_activity_main`
value:`MainActivity`

also here is my java code will i have to change anything here?

```
package tip.calculator;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class TipCalculator extends Activity 
{
private EditText myEditField;
private EditText myEditField2;
private Button enter;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myEditField2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.billText);
    myEditField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.percentText);
    enter = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    enter.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView textView;

            textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

            final EditText myEditField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.percentText);
            final EditText myEditField2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.billText);

            float percentage;
            float percentageInp;
            float billAmount;
            double output; 
            String output1;

            percentageInp = Float.parseFloat(myEditField.getText().toString());
            billAmount = Float.parseFloat(myEditField2.getText().toString());

            percentage = ((float)percentageInp /100);

            output = (double)(billAmount * percentage);

            double result = output * 100;
            result = Math.round(result);
            result = result / 100;

            output1 = Double.toString(result);

            textView.setText(output1);

        }
    });
}
}
```

manifest.xml ...

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="tip.calculator"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="13"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:debuggable="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".TipCalculator"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

here is my strings.xml

```
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Tip Calculator</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>

</resources>
```

Comment: You don't need to change any code. You just need to edit strings.xml. Post your strings.xml and tell us what error you got when editing it.

Comment: Change the value of the title_activity_main to your title.

Comment: i can't find the file with the error i try to run it and it says your file contains errors... on second let me look at log cat

Comment: @Nerd it stills says i have an error, although i can't find it

Comment: go to res->values->strings.xml

Comment: the error is... [2012-07-24 10:14:19 - Tip Calculator] Error in an XML file: aborting build... when i change the value in manifest.xml

Comment: @Boe-Dev what would i change there?

Comment: ok i have posted strings @ the bottom

Comment: 2012-07-24 10:14:19 - Tip Calculator] Error in an XML file: aborting build... is what is says

Comment: add this line on the top to your strings.xml: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

Comment: Then save and try running it.

Comment: there are no erros but how do i change the  name of the application

Comment: did you change the value of `title_activity_main` to `TipCalcuLator` ?

Comment: i did in strings.xml where else do i do it?

Comment: oh mainfest.xml as well, thanks to all for help...

Comment: More and better answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199940/android-app-name-not-being-displayed

Answer (score 4):

change the label

> android:label="Tip Calculator"

or change your strings.xml

```
<string name="app_name">Tip Calculator</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="title_activity_main">Tip Calculator</string>
```

Comment: So just remove :: @string/ and replace into own title

Answer (score 3):

This is because android does not allow for two different labels for the app_name and main activity name. But in case you want to use two different labels at the same time you could accomplish it as follow;

The name for your App to be shown on app menu

```
<application> android:lable = "@string/app_name" </application>
```

And the different label when you launch the activity;

in your onCreate() method of the main activity put;

```
this.setTitle("Your Title for the Activity");
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats just an error in eclipse sometimes, close eclipse then clean your project and it should be fine