# Android Application Getting First Activity Name

Tags: android, android-manifest

Hi all my manifest look like below

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.android.mic.controller"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>            
    </activity>
 </application>
 </manifest>
```

My problem is when I install application  the name appears beneath the application icon is of

```
   android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
```

and not

```
   android:label="@string/app_name"
```

But when I go to setting->Application->manage Application the second one is appearing.

How can I set my application with  `android:label="@string/app_name"` I already see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444040/naming-my-application-in-android)  but no idea.

Answer (score 1):

```
android:label in <activity>
```

A user-readable label for the activity. The label is displayed on-screen when the activity must be represented to the user. It's often displayed along with the activity icon.
If this attribute is not set, the label set for the application as a whole is used instead

That's why your application show name `android:label="@string/title_activity_main"` in first but when you go to manage application it shows the default application name.

check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)